# Encountered an error while trying to use bind variable in dynamic sql for table deletion

Tags: sql, oracle11g

So, i'm trying to write dynamic sql with bind variable to delete table. Maybe i need to add somewhere qoutes or what? I have tried adding them but it didn't change. I have written tables creation almost in the same way (using bind variables too) and it works fine. I have no idea why deletion doesn't work :/ Therefore, i'm asking you guys to help me to figure out what's wrong. :)

Sorry for links, but in this way the code will be more readable.

Here's the code:

```
PROCEDURE create_tables IS

   .............
  ...more code...
   .............

33   PROCEDURE empty_table(in_table_name VARCHAR2) IS
34     l_statement VARCHAR2(100) := 'DELETE :bind_table_name';
35   BEGIN
36     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_statement
37       USING in_table_name;    
38   END;
39
40 BEGIN  
41   FOR i IN 1..g_tables.COUNT LOOP
42     IF check_existence(g_tables(i)) = 0
43       THEN
44         create_table(g_tables(i));
45       ELSE
46         empty_table(g_tables(i));
47     END IF;
48   END LOOP;
49 END create_tables;
```

And here's the error message:

```
Error report -
ORA-00903: invalid table name
ORA-06512: at "LATVYT.THANDLER", line 36
ORA-06512: at "LATVYT.THANDLER", line 46
ORA-06512: at line 4
00903. 00000 -  "invalid table name"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

This is how g_tables look:

```
TYPE TLIST IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30);
g_tables TLIST := TLIST('OPERACIJA', 'PRODUKTAS', 'PRODUKTO_OPERACIJA', 'PLANAS', 'DARBUOTOJAS', 'UZDUOTIS');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting a table is a *data definition language* (DDL) operation. Parameter binding is not supported for DDL. Even in an INSERT statement, you cannot use parameter binding to replace the table name.

Use simple string concatenation:

```
PROCEDURE empty_table(in_table_name VARCHAR2) IS
     l_statement VARCHAR2(100) 
BEGIN
   l_statement := 'DELETE ' || in_table_name;
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_statement
END;
```

Comment: This helped me out:) I guess i should do more reading about bind variables. Btw, thanks a lot! :)